# Dynamic Stylesheet, toggle CSS rule by name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to ask you the following question: 
"How can i **toggle** css rules in dynamically generated stylesheet?"

*Problem Description:*

Suppose we have 3 Buttons like you see it this sample picture below:
[image]

Clicking on them should disable or enable the styling. So the red buttons class .red {...} should be disabled temporarly and if I click it again it should be enabled.

Please note: I don't need the toggle functionality for the buttons, which I already have, or in other words the toggle state.

*Question:*
My question regards the dynamic stylesheet I have created. I have an instance of it in my variable called `stylesheet` and if i print it to the console, I get the CSSStyleSheet object. This object has a property called `cssRules` which is an array of all my rules. So in our example it would be an array of 3 elements (one rule for each color).
If I click now the red button I want to toggle it's rule in the stylesheet I have and if I click it again I want to reenable it. I know it would be easy to delete the rule and add it back again, but I would have to store it somewhere and what if the user clicks all 3 buttons? I need to scale this to at least 20 buttons.

**Update:** 
Created a fiddle for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/doomsayer2/52ayw0od/20/

Comment: So I would need like a method `toggleStyle(name)` where I pass the name of the button and toggle the css rule in the stylesheet.

Comment: Pls attach your code to your question! Without code, it's hard to help!

Comment: _which is an array of all my rules_ What is the structure of the rule?

Comment: If you really need a code i need to create an example fiddle for that. Because this whole logic is in a bigger project. However, see the updated question where I posted the structure of the rules.

Comment: I created a fiddle showing the problem. I think I described it there well. If you need more explanation please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood well, but the proper way to toggle style on a tag would be to toggle the class. There is even a method for that is JavaScript. For example

```
document.getElementById('btnRedAdd').classList.toggle('red')
```